# jquery - ajax request specifying content type as html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the modernish jquery 1.5 ajax request. To a page on the same domain.
I'm trying to improve upon behaviour in an intranet site using grease monkey and jquery.

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax("anotherpage-response.html")
.success(function(data) {alert("cmp"); console.log(data);})
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Its currently being returned as a string. Any idea how I can get it returned as a dom like object which I can proccess using jquery selectors ???

I think im after something like `fileType: html` but it doesnt seem to be an option in the ajax request. Maybe I just need to read the api properly ???

Thanks

Comment: Just pass `data` to jQuery? `$(data)`

Comment: Btw. the option would be `dataType`, but the documentation says: *Returns HTML as plain text*, so that won't help I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read up on jquery's documentation on this subject: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
The thing you are looking for probably is the following: **dataType**.

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'request.html', 
    succes: function(data){ 
        .. do something here! ..
    }, 
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Does this work? The documentation says: *Returns HTML as plain text*. Have you tried it?

Comment: This mainly sets the headers for the return value. You can then use a $(data) to create a jquery object from it. But this doesn't act as a normal body. You can use data.find('body') to find and manipulate this object. You have to work around this issue, and jquery seriously needs to take some action on this. I you have to do a lot of manipulation consider returning a json-object and building the html with javascript

Comment: Then I have to say that your answer is misleading. It appears you are suggesting to use `dataType: 'html'` and it should work. But adding this does not improve the situation and leaves the OP still where it is now.... not necessarily helpful.

Answer (score 3):

No matter what you will get back a string as plain text.

From the jQuery docs on dataType:

""html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM."

You can always turn plaintext into a dom object though..

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'request.html', 
succes: function(data){ 
  $(data) // This is now (kind of) a DOM object that you can use jQuery selectors on
}, 
dataType: 'html'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.4 and below, you could specify the content type by passing the `dataType`. In later versions, jQuery tries to determine the content type for you.

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "anotherpage-response.html", 
    success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
        if (ct.indexOf(‘html’) > -1) {
            //handle html content
        }
        else if (ct.indexOf(‘json’) > -1) {      
            //handle json object
        } 
    }
});
```